# Setting up an IP Camera on raspberry pi

Tags: webcam, camera, streaming-video

I'd like to setup my raspberry pi to work as an IP Camera. Can you please point me to guides on how to do that - I am unable to find resources in particular for the two-way audio part of it. I am looking for open source projects that i can combine/enhance to get this working.

*Note: I had previously asked this question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968346/setting-up-an-ip-camera-on-linux) and was advised to ask it here instead.*

Comment: [I wrote a blog on how to stream video pretty well from the pi - Adding audio wont be to difficult and is supported](http://pkula.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/live-video-stream-from-raspberry-pi.html)

Answer (score 1):

there's no audio input on RaspberryPi, you most definitely should reconsider the hardware platform for your project. or you may try to use usb-connected video cameras with built-in microphone.

video capture works quite well using `motion`, including web-interface to access the camera output. haven't tried it with the sound, mostly because of lack of the microphone.

Comment: I am using a USB camera with microphone on it so that's where the sound would be coming from. Motion seems like a one-directional sort of solution from what I've seen - I don't think there's a way to do client->camera audio with it at all...

Answer (score 1):

motion can be used to stream a webcam as an IP camera.